# How can I call one function from another function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to call a function from another function in Node.js. I am new to this language, so I am trying to implement it in a simple way, but, it is not working as expected. What am I missing?

```
//Reading from file
var params = require('line-reader’);

var count = 1;
params.eachLine('test.csv', function(line, last) {
     if (count!=1) {
        //Some code
        count++;
     } else {
        //Some code
        count++;
     }

     if (last) {
        // **Call myFunc with count as argument**
        myFunc(count);
     }
});


// Actual code which I am using

function myFunc(count) {
     tradeoff_analytics.dilemmas(count, function(err, res) {
     if (err)
         console.log(err);
     else
         console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
     });
}
```

Yes, the method was undefined, so I was getting an undefined error.
Now I have copied the actual code and I am getting this error now:

```
[Error: Missing required parameters: columns, subject, options]
```

Comment: Where is `myFunc` defined?

Comment: @miparnisari I doubt its existance.

Comment: It's worth noting that this isn't really a node question, but a javascript question, as node is a server side javascript environment and this turns out to be a question about how to define a function.

Comment: Now that problem has nothing to do with the code you are showing us

Comment: Yes. That was my mistake and solved by @miparnisari

Comment: I don't know what `tradeoff_analytics.dilemmas()` is, but I would guess that you aren't passing the required parameters: `columns, subject, options`

Comment: Tradeof_analytics is a service by IBM, you can find it on cloud. This method takes argument and do some analytics, and returns some result. So in my case count is my argument but it is not being recognized inside the tradeoff_anaytics method.

Answer (score 4):

Your myFunc isn't properly defined, change this:

```
myFunc(count, function() {
     console.log(count);
});
```

Into this:

```
function myFunc(count){
     console.log(count);
}
```

Or this:

```
var myFunc = function(count) {
    console.log(count);
};
```